# What does "I feel friendly" mean？

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, american-english

If I want to express the feeling that other people are very friendly to me, what is the proper way to say it？ Is it okay to say:"I feel you are very friendly"? Is there any better way to say so?

Besides, what does "I feel friendly" mean? Or is it even gramatically correct? Thank you!

Comment: When a boy tells a girl, *I feel you are very friendly to me*, the girl would think *are you asking me out on a date?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say, "I feel friendly", you are saying, "I think that I am friendly." You could say, "I feel you are very friendly", but it would sound a little strange. If you're okay with being somewhat informal, "You're a friendly sort" could be a nice thing to say.

If you think that sounds kind of flat, you could elaborate. You almost need to know exactly what specific behavior you're complimenting, e.g. is he being cordial, mellow and easy-going, or compassionate, loving, and understanding, etc. "You're amiable" or "You're likeable" or "you're a very kind person" or an almost infinite number of similar sentences would convey the idea that you are happy with the other person's overall disposition (with somewhat varying connotations); but to address their friendliness to *you* specifically rather than overall agreeableness, you'll almost invariably need to construct the sentence to accommodate inserting "to me" at the end. "You show a great deal of patience and kindness to me, and you've ever been abundantly and amicably affable and amiable in your dealings with me." (Well, perhaps that's borderline on repetitive, but that seldom hurts in getting a point like this across.) The only problem is that you'll find people like me who haven't read the dictionary all the way through, so use words starting with "a" in case they made it through the "a"s. :)

Comment: I considered it to be somewhat brief, but you are welcome for what it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could say something like this: I am glad you are so well disposed towards me.

'I feel friendly' while not grammatically inaccurate sounds childish and is not usually addressed about oneself.

Comment: I would be thrilled if someone told me that he was appreciative of my positive disposition towards him, but that could sound stuffy in some informal contexts.